# Convergence of the superposition of two random processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, probability-limit-theorems

Let $Z_n$ be a stochastic process such that $P(Z_n/a(n) \le x|Z_n>0) \to P(\xi \le x)$, where $a(n) \to \infty$ is a sequence of positive real numbers.

Let $N(t)$ be an integer valued  stochastic process independent of $Z_n$ such that $P(N(t)/b(t) \le x) \to P(\eta \le x)$, where $b(t) \to \infty$ is a sequence of positive real numbers.

Consider the superposition $Z_{N(t)}$. Is it true that 
$P(Z_{N(t)}/a(N(t)) \le x|Z_{N(t)}>0) \to P(\xi \le x)$?

What about $P(Z_{N(t)}/a(b(t)) \le x|Z_{N(t)}>0) \to ???? $